# How can I cancel a delete on my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

I've deleted a question of mine by mistake, is there a way to cancel it ?

Comment: Um. Go back to it and click the "undelete" link?

Comment: Thanks, I'd to do F5 to see the undelete link ...
Is there a way to see my deleted post somewhere?

Comment: Go to your profile -> tab Questions -> link `deleted recent questions`.

Comment: @fedorqui: Hope you mean **Activity** tab -> **questions**

Comment: @Arulkumar when viewing own profile, Activity is the default tab.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

In the end of the **Activity** tab -> **questions** section you can find a link stated **deleted recent questions**, click on the link it will shows the recent deleted questions.

In the list select your required question and click on the **Undelete** link, you can retain the question to visibility to all.

[image: Undelete question]

---

To undelete the answer, you can try with **Activity** tab -> **answers**, then click on the **deleted recent answers** link.

[image: Undelete answer]

Comment: Did it always work like this? I could have sworn in the past when I clicked 'undelete' on a post it just cast a vote to undelete, and the post remained deleted...

Comment: @user333703: The post needs to go through at least as difficult a process to undelete as to delete, so if it was deleted by the owner, it can be undeleted by the owner, but if it was deleted by votes it needs to be undeleted by votes (or a moderator), and if it was deleted by a moderator it needs to be undeleted by a moderator.